# Disable Use of @deprecated Angular Classes/Functions

Tags: angular, tslint

Is there a tslint rule or check that a project isn't using deprecated Angular classes or functions?

I've found that during development of two Angular 5.x projects, developers have used the `Http` class which was replaced by `HttpClient` from `@angular/common/http`. Needless to say, we don't want to be using deprecated classes on brand new projects.

Answer (score 1):

There is TSLint [`deprecation` rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/deprecation/) for that.

Add

```
"deprecation": false
```

to tslint.json configuration.

This should disable `use @angular/common/http instead` deprecation note.